# PHP array assigned with and

Tags: php

Just learning php and looking into someone else's code. I'm not sure what is happening in this function with the word 'and' on the left side of the = operator. It seems like it is a 'silent' if is being used eg.
 if $arry =true and $array2 = true then $array2 += 'somthing';

I cant seem to find any reference to this anywhere online.

```
  function get_list_filter($filter = array()) {
     global $current_user;
    $sql = array();
    $filter["clientID"]         and $sql[] = sprintf("(WD_domain.clientID = %d)",$filter["clientID"]);
    $filter["showDomainName"]   and $sql[] = sprintf("(WD_domain.domain LIKE '%%%s%%')",$filter["showDomainName"]);
    $filter["showManaged"]      and $sql[] = sprintf("(WD_domain.managed = %d)",$filter["showManaged"]);
    return $sql;
  }
```

Comment: i love the php compiler. it lets code be so... individual!

Comment: This technique is known as a [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), or short-circuiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if the left side of the `and` evaluates to true, the right side will be executed also. In essence, if `clientID` evaluates to true (is non-false), then `sprintf("(WD_domain.clientID = %d)",$filter["clientID"])` will be added to the `$sql` array.

It's a lazy way of doing this:

```
if($filter["clientID"]) {
    $sql[] = sprintf("(WD_domain.clientID = %d)",$filter["clientID"]);
}
```

Comment: Ah OK this is what I was after as an explanation, as the 'and' in the single line doesn't help make it clear why the second element value is being assigned.
Is their a name for this type of short hand evaluating?

Comment: @Elijha: It's called short-circuiting. See my comment on your question for a link.

Answer (score 5):

```
$foo and $bar = "baz";
```

Is just a confusing way of saying

```
if ($foo)
    $bar = "baz";
```

Shame on whoever wrote that.

Comment: Its not always bad: `confirmed() or redirect('/not-confirmed);`

Comment: @Petah: It's funny how only about half of the PHP users I've seen use that can actually explain how and why it works.

Comment: well I figure the only thing 'wrong' with it is readability, and user knowledge. I also couldn't find anything out about it by searching. Though I see from looking for the term 'short-circuiting' (given by boltlock) some languages use the keywords 'sand' and 'sor' which would give a better visual clue when reading the code that somthings going on.